# React router render component twice

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, react-router-v4

I have routs with children and on the first load, everything working fine but once I'm staring through the site, the components starting to render twice. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.
This is the route top structure:

```
<React.Suspense fallback={<span>Loading...</span>}>
    <Switch>
       <Route path={"/dashboard/optionOne"} component={OptionOne} />
       <Route path={"/dashboard/OptionTwo"} component={OptionTwo}/>
    <Switch>
</React.Suspense>
```

Then these are the children route:
**OptionOne Component**

```
    <Switch>
       <Route exact path={path} component={OptionOneContainer}/>
       <Route path={`${path}/subChildOne`} component={SubChildOne}/>
       <Route path={`${path}/:subChildTwo`} component={SubChildTwo}/>
    </Switch>
```

**OptionTwo component**

```
    <Switch>
       <Route exact path={path} component={OptionTwoContainer}/>
       <Route path={`${path}/OptionTwoSubChildOne`} component={OptionTwoSubChildOne}/>
       <Route path={`${path}/:OptionTwoSubChildTwo`} component={OptionTwoSubChildTwo}/>
    </Switch>
```

I have a top component header that helps navigate through the site dashboard:

```
const navigate=(path)=>{
  history.push(path)
}

<div>
  <Link to={"/dashboard/optionOne"}>OptionOne</Link>
  <div onClick={()=>navigate("/dashboard/optionOne")}>OptionOne</div>
  <div onClick={()=>navigate("/dashboard/optionTwo")}>OptionTwo</div>
</div>
```

Once clicking Link to navigate or even using the history.push, components rendering twice.
Any suggestions?

Comment: In my experience, in 90% cases the problem is not in your routes, but in your components. Show the components code Better yet - make a minimal reproducible example

Comment: I'm sure this issue coming from the routes since no dependency is changing while navigating between components. I checked it thousands of times and I'm wondering if something is wrong with my routes

Comment: sidenote: you should use `@nickname` if you want the recipient to receive a notification

Comment: Well... you don't know what happens, right? Will you bet on that the error is not in your components? And I've just received a 100 bounty for a similar question about routes, but with error in a component :)

Comment: @x00 I have to admit that after 8 hours I find the issue and you were right, BUT the solution to this issue was to change the hierarchy of the routes and prevent a component to re-render when navigating between the routes. Thanks for the help and motivation

Comment: Glad you've managed it

Comment: No offence, but I've voted to close the question, because it lacks crucial details and won't  help future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

In my case. The issue because the `StrictMode` that explained very detail here

https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#detecting-unexpected-side-effects
https://www.heissenberger.at/en/blog/react-components-reder-twice/

The main reason is **React.StrictMode** which was introduced in version 16.3.0. Back then it only could be used for class components. With the release of 16.8.0 it is also applied for hooks.

**StrictMode** is a tool for highlighting potential problems in an application. Like Fragment, StrictMode does not render any visible UI. It activates additional checks and warnings for its descendants. ‒ official React Documentation

**React.StrictMode** currently helps you with:

1. Identifying components with unsafe lifecycles
2. Warning about legacy string ref API usage
3. Warning about deprecated findDOMNode usage
4. Detecting unexpected side effects
5. Detecting legacy context API

In most cases it will throw an error message into the browser console log. It fails to automatically detect render side effects as they often can be non-deterministic behavior.

To detect side effects the following functions are invoked twice:

1. Class component constructor, render, and shouldComponentUpdate
   methods
2. Class component static getDerivedStateFromProps method
3. Function component bodies
4. State updater functions
5. Functions passed to useState, useMemo, or useReducer (any Hook)